# What is the location of attachments that I download from the Gmail app?

Tags: gmail, file-system, attachments

I can't find where the files are saved after I download them from an email message.
I'd be glad if you could direct me to the location.

Answer (score 20):

That should be `/sdcard/Downloads`, replace `/sdcard` with wherever your "data storage" is. You can also access them using the App "Downloads".

Comment: Also you need program like ES File explorer to browse /sdcard/Downloads.